# Sum of squares and sum of cubes

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

**Problem:**
Suppose that three non-negative numbers are restricted by the condition that the sum of their squares is equal to 27. Using critical point analysis,with 2nd derivative and/or boundary tests as needed, find the maximum and minimum values of the sum of their cubes.

**My attempt:**
I expressed the problem as $x^2+y^2+z^2=27$, and expressed $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ and found partial derivates. However, I can't seem to fit sum of cubes in this problem.

Comment: Try [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)

Answer (score 1):

K.defaoite mentioned Lagrange multipliers; let's see what that would look like. Equating gradients, we have
$$
\langle 3x^2,3y^2,3z^2\rangle = \lambda \langle 2x,2y,2z\rangle
$$ Written symmetrically,
$$
2\lambda =3x=3y=3z
$$
$$
12\lambda^2 =9x^2+9y^2+9z^2
$$
$$
\lambda^2 =9\cdot 27/12;\lambda = \pm 9/2
$$We can discard $\lambda =-9/2$ by the non-negativity requirement:
$$
\langle x^2,y^2,z^2\rangle =3\langle x,y,z\rangle
$$So either at most two of $x,y,z$ are zero, giving $81\sqrt{3}$, or $x=y=z=3$, giving $81$.

**Another way without critical point analysis.** By AMGM, $x^3+y^3+z^3\geq 3 xyz$, with equality when $x=y=z$. With the condition $x^2+y^2+z^2=27$, this gives the minimum value of $81$. On the other hand, $x^3+y^3+z^3\leq \max\{x,y,z\}^3$; in other words, the maximum is achieved by maximizing one variable. This occurs at $x=\sqrt{27},y=z=0$, for a maximum of $81\sqrt{3}$.